# ガベージコレクションについて

Tags: javascript, node.js

JavaScriptのガベージコレクション（以下GC）について質問です。

以下の二例で前者だけ変数objがGCされる理由がわかりません。どちらも監視対象への参照は切っており、global.gc()の実行されるタイミングも同じ同期処理内なので変化はないように思えます。なにが原因で異なる結果が生じているのでしょうか。

```js
// GCされる例
hoge();

function hoge(){
    let obj = {}
    const fr = new FinalizationRegistry(function(value){
        console.log(value);
    });
    fr.register(obj, 'object');
    obj = null;
    global.gc();
}
```

```js
// GCされない例
hoge();
global.gc();

function hoge(){
    let obj = {}
    const fr = new FinalizationRegistry(function(value){
        console.log(value);
    });
    fr.register(obj, 'object');
    obj = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

おそらく`object`が出力されるかどうかで、GCされるされないを判断しているのだと思いますが、`fr`が`hoge()`のローカル変数なので、コールバック関数の設定が`hoge()`の外に伝播していないだけでしょう．
`fr`をグローバルスコープにしたら、`object`と出力されました．

```js
const fr = new FinalizationRegistry(function(value){
    console.log(value);
});

function hoge(){
    let obj = {}
    fr.register(obj, 'object');
    obj = null;
}

hoge();
global.gc();
```

Comment: ありがとうございます、ご指摘のとおりFinalizationRegistryインスタンスがローカル変数である点が理由でした。前者の例では関数内のローカル変数であるため到達性が保持されていて、後者の例では既にそれを失っていることからインスタンスごとGCされていることが理解できました。

Answer (score 1):

[FinalizationRegistry: Notes on cleanup callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry#notes_on_cleanup_callbacks)

> There are also situations where even implementations that normally call cleanup callbacks are **unlikely to call them**:
>
> - When the JavaScript program shuts down entirely (for instance, closing a tab in a browser).
> - When the FinalizationRegistry instance itself is **no longer reachable by JavaScript code**.

**test.js**

```
function hoge(){
    let obj = {}
    const fr = new FinalizationRegistry(function(value){
        console.log(value);
    });
    fr.register(obj, 'object');
    obj = null;

    return fr; // return FinalizationRegistry instance
}

const _ = hoge();
global.gc();

// 実行結果
object
```

Comment: ありがとうございます、まさにMDNに記載されているとおりでした。さっそく試しにいくつかの手段でFinalizationRegistryインスタンスへの到達性を維持しながら実行したところ、想定どおりのGCの挙動を確認することができました。